# Sort all dataframes by a single column within each dataframe in R

Tags: r, sorting, dataframe

I have a list of dataframes from 1:323 which are mrns[[1]]:mrns[[323]], and each dataframe has a column called "ar.cat" which categorizes continuous data from another column ar.value.

```
> dput(head(mrns[[1]]))
ar.value = c(32.8, 32.8, 32.8, 
32.8, 32.8, 32.8), ar.cat = c("HIGH", "HIGH", "HIGH", "HIGH", 
"HIGH", "HIGH")),

> dput(head(mrns[[2]]))
ar.value = c(2.7, 2.7, 2.7, 2.7, 2.7, 
2.7), ar.cat = c("LOW", "LOW", "LOW", "LOW", "LOW", "LOW"
)),
```

"ar.cat" has values of low, medium, and high. Each dataframe has the same value of "ar.cat" for all of the rows of the dataframe. So for every row in dataframe 1, it will have a "high" value, then for every row in dataframe 2, it will have a "low" value, etc.

I am trying to order all of the 323 dataframes by the "ar.cat" column, so that the first however many dataframes (1:105) have values of "high", the next (106:207) have a value of "low", then the next (208:323) have a value of "medium". I'm assuming alphabetical order will be easiest.

What I have so far is the following:

```
sortCat <- function(df) {
  sort(df$ar.cat)
  return(df)
}

sorted <- lapply(mrns, sortCat)
```

But that will order every "ar.cat" column within each dataframe, not between all dataframes.

Does anybody have any suggestions?

Comment: I would be tempted to add a `df_index` to each data frame (`mrns[[1]]` has `df_index = 1`, `mrns[[2]] = df_index = 2`, etc), then bind all of the data frames together; sort them as one data frame, and then if the list structure is important, `split` them back into a list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this with sapply:

```
order(sapply(mrns, function(x){unique(x$ar.cat)}))
```

But I think it only works if your strings are character, not factor

Comment: Wow, that was perfect. Thank you!